# Is this the true difference between using PhoneGap and simply opening a WebView in my application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview

I was lately assigned to create a PhoneGap application for 4 different mobile platforms. After playing around with PhoneGap for a while , i decided it wasnt good to serve my purposes as there were no push-notification plugins for the WP7 and BB platforms.

So i went native. I wrote native code for the different platforms that simply does 2 things:

**1)** *implement push notifications*

**2)** *open an in-app webView*

My plan was that now with the webView i can open my "html-javascript web page" that i would use with the phonegap framework and it would be the same thing..

**However...** lately i found out that some javascript wont run in the BB (some older versions of OS) . So now i think i understand whats the difference between using PhoneGap and by simple opening a WebView.

**IF** i was using PhoneGap , the html-javascript code that i would write , would be *translated* through the framework to *native* code so it would run in the mobile. Now that i try to run javascript through the Web Browser , it simply wont run if the device doesnt support it.

Am i right here? Is this the final big difference between these 2 things?

Comment: Why -1 ? What is wrong with this question ? Is a great question that could help others in my position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is basically a precompiled native library for multiple platforms that translates native SDK functions to JavaScript functions. In the implementation it tries to have the same naming convention on every platform even when the native SDK works completely different (just like jQuery makes it possible to call one function even when different browsers need different ways of having functions called).

So for example in PhoneGap you can call a function to take a picture with the device's camera with a simple JavaScript function call (with callback) whereas a plain webview cannot do this.

Keep in mind that PhoneGap does not get native speeds with this approach and for a big project I can not advise to use this because eventually you will run into performance problems and/or rendering issues between platforms which will lead to platform dependent code after all -> then you wish you just made 4 different native apps.